# Excel VBA taking long time to copy date from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy data from one excel to another using VBA. But its taking more than 15 mins for 30K lines. Is there a way I could make it faster?

I need to align 39 columns from New Report workbook to ACQ047 WB.

Below is my code:

```
Sub alignment()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\raja\Desktop\New Report.xls")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\raja\Desktop\ACQ047.xlsx")

Dim Lastrow As Long


y.Sheets("unmached").Range("A2").Activate
y.Sheets("unmached").Rows(ActiveCell.Row & ":" & Rows.Count).Delete Shift:=xlUp




x.Sheets("New Report").Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
Lastrow = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False '!!!!
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual '!!!!

For i = 1 To Lastrow
CopyVal = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 2).Value
CopyVal2 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 6).Value
CopyVal3 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 8).Value
CopyVal4 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 11).Value
CopyVal5 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 12).Value
CopyVal6 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 14).Value
CopyVal7 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 16).Value
CopyVal8 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 18).Value
CopyVal9 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 19).Value
CopyVal10 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 20).Value
CopyVal11 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 21).Value
CopyVal12 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 22).Value
CopyVal13 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 23).Value
CopyVal14 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 25).Value
CopyVal15 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 26).Value
CopyVal16 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 28).Value
CopyVal17 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 30).Value
CopyVal18 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 32).Value
CopyVal19 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 33).Value
CopyVal20 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 35).Value
CopyVal21 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 40).Value
CopyVal22 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 41).Value
CopyVal23 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 49).Value
CopyVal24 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 50).Value
CopyVal25 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 46).Value
CopyVal26 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 48).Value
CopyVal27 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 43).Value
CopyVal28 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 29).Value
CopyVal29 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 53).Value
CopyVal30 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 54).Value
CopyVal31 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 55).Value
CopyVal32 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 56).Value
CopyVal33 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 57).Value
CopyVal34 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 59).Value
CopyVal35 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 60).Value
CopyVal36 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 61).Value
CopyVal37 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 62).Value
CopyVal38 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 63).Value
CopyVal39 = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 64).Value



  y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 38).Value = CopyVal39
  y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 37).Value = CopyVal38
  y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 36).Value = CopyVal37
  y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 35).Value = CopyVal36
  y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 34).Value = CopyVal35
  y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 33).Value = CopyVal34
  y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 32).Value = CopyVal33
  y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 31).Value = CopyVal32
  y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 30).Value = CopyVal31
  y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 29).Value = CopyVal30
  y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 28).Value = CopyVal29
  y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 27).Value = CopyVal28
  y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 26).Value = CopyVal27
  y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 25).Value = CopyVal26
  y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 24).Value = CopyVal25
  y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 23).Value = CopyVal24
  y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 22).Value = CopyVal23
y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 21).Value = CopyVal22
y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 20).Value = CopyVal21
y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 19).Value = CopyVal20
y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 18).Value = CopyVal19
y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 17).Value = CopyVal18
y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 16).Value = CopyVal17
y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 15).Value = CopyVal16
y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 14).Value = CopyVal15
y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 13).Value = CopyVal14
y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 12).Value = CopyVal13
y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 11).Value = CopyVal12
y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 10).Value = CopyVal11
y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 9).Value = CopyVal10
y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 8).Value = CopyVal9
y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 7).Value = CopyVal8
y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 6).Value = CopyVal7
y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 5).Value = CopyVal6
y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 4).Value = CopyVal5
y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 3).Value = CopyVal4
y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 2).Value = CopyVal3
y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1).Value = CopyVal2
y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = CopyVal

Next


Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic '!!!!
Application.ScreenUpdating = True '!!!

y.Sheets("unmached").Range("A1").Select

ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Select

ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

MsgBox " Report Generated"



End Sub
```

Comment: broadly speaking you want to access the worksheet as few times as possible. So if you could pull in your data (all 30k lines) once and then output to the new worksheet once it would be very quick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this with 55k lines of just numbers and it took roughly 45s.

I just inputted the original data into an array and the looped through the array to put the data back into the new sheet.

You will need to confirm if I have captured the correct cells etc.

```
Option Explicit

Sub alignment()

    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook

    Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\raja\Desktop\New Report.xls")
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\raja\Desktop\ACQ047.xlsx")


    y.Sheets("unmached").Range("A2").Activate
    y.Sheets("unmached").Rows(ActiveCell.Row & ":" & Rows.Count).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    x.Sheets("New Report").Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert

    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Lastrow = x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False '!!!!
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual '!!!!

    Dim DataArray As Variant
    ReDim DataArray(39)

    For i = 1 To Lastrow

        With x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1")

            DataArray = Array(.Offset(i, 2).Value, .Offset(i, 6).Value, .Offset(i, 8).Value, _
                              .Offset(i, 11).Value, .Offset(i, 12).Value, .Offset(i, 14).Value, _
                              .Offset(i, 16).Value, .Offset(i, 18).Value, .Offset(i, 19).Value, _
                              .Offset(i, 20).Value, .Offset(i, 21).Value, .Offset(i, 22).Value, _
                              .Offset(i, 23).Value, .Offset(i, 25).Value, .Offset(i, 26).Value, _
                              .Offset(i, 28).Value, .Offset(i, 30).Value, .Offset(i, 32).Value, _
                              .Offset(i, 33).Value, .Offset(i, 35).Value, .Offset(i, 40).Value, _
                              .Offset(i, 41).Value, .Offset(i, 49).Value, .Offset(i, 50).Value, _
                              .Offset(i, 46).Value, .Offset(i, 48).Value, .Offset(i, 43).Value, _
                              .Offset(i, 29).Value, .Offset(i, 53).Value, .Offset(i, 54).Value, _
                              .Offset(i, 55).Value, .Offset(i, 56).Value, .Offset(i, 57).Value, _
                              .Offset(i, 59).Value, .Offset(i, 60).Value, .Offset(i, 61).Value, _
                              .Offset(i, 62).Value, .Offset(i, 63).Value, .Offset(i, 64).Value)

        End With

        With y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)

           Dim ArrayPos As Long

            For ArrayPos = 0 To 38
               .Offset(1, 38 - ArrayPos).Value = DataArray(39 - ArrayPos)
            Next ArrayPos

        End With

    Next i

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic '!!!!
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True '!!!

    y.Sheets("unmached").Range("A1").Select

    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

    x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Select

    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

    MsgBox " Report Generated"

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Jean thanks for your edited code. I dont have any know on arraypos. I guess your Array contains a wrong line---  x.Sheets("New Rep2-1ort").Range("A1").Offset(i, 33).Value, _

So it throws me a out of script error.

Comment: @YousuvaRaja Not sure where that line came from, I though it was from your code, but I have corrected to come from `x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A1").Offset(i, 33).Value` Please check it again. Also I am not sure what you mean _I dont have any know on arraypos_ `ArrayPos` is just a variable I declared to use to extract data from the `DaraArray`

Comment: Thanks Jean it worked and just taking less than a 2 minutes :)

Comment: @YousuvaRaja I am happy that it works, remember to up vote and mark the correct answer to your question.

Comment: Hi Jean am new to this site and I dont know where to up vote.. can you please help me?

Comment: @YousuvaRaja there are Up and Down arrows to the left of the top of the answer, you do it there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code as an example for how to perform this kind of task by only accessing the worksheet twice. Generally, I try to avoid copy and paste in VBA but this should speed things up nicely

```
Sub Test()
    x.Sheets("New Report").Range("A:A,C:C,E:E").Copy
    y.Sheets("Unmached").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code as per your requirement. This will not take more than 5-10 SECONDS

Change the sheet name and workbook name as required and do one thing, check if ranges are accurate. hope you got the idea let me know if you still face issues -

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws1, ws2 As Workbook

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws2 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Praveen Behera files\book2.xlsx")

'l is lastrow
 l = ws1.sheets("Sheet1").range("A500000").end(xlup).row

ws1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("" & "C2:C" & l & ",G2:G" & l & ",I2:I" & l & ",L2:L" & l & ",M2:M" & l & ",O2:O" & l & ",Q2:Q" & l & ",S2:S" & l & ",T2:T" & l & ",U2:U" & l & ",V2:V" & l & ",W2:W" & l & ",X2:X" & l & ",Z2:Z" & l & ",AA2:AA" & l & ",AC2:AC" & l & ",AD2:AD" & l & ",AE2:AE" & l & ",AG2:AG" & l & ",AH2:AH" & l & ",AJ2:AJ" & l & ",AO2:AO" & l & ",AP2:AP" & l & ",AR2:AR" & l & ",AU2:AU" & l & ",AW2:AW" & l & ",AX2:AX" & l & ",AY2:AY" & l & ",BB2:BB" & l & ",BC2:BC" & l & ",BD2:BD" & l & "").Copy Destination:=ws2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")

ws1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("" & "BE2:BE" & l & ",BF2:BF" & l & ",BH2:BH" & l & ",BI2:BI" & l & ",BJ2:BJ" & l & ",BK2:BK" & l & ",BL2:BL" & l & ",BM2:BM" & l & "").Copy Destination:=ws2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AF2")

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Given that your ranges aren't correct this is pretty much a duplicate of the answer I already provided

Comment: this is my own answer. Rest, let the asker decide the ranges. @Yousuva Raja, Please check the ranges, check if required.

Comment: Hi Callum and Praveen, thanks for your suggestion. After Q column everything gets messed up and the ranges are pasting in different columns. But this is much faster than what i had. Thanks again for your support:)